# Why dependend dropdownlist is gone after trying to use pattern in different field?

Tags: regex, yii2

strange situation here. I have a dependent `dropdownlist` and the next field is `customer phone`. In that field I'm using this pattern to allow only numbers plus the `+` sign:

```
['customer_phone', 'match',
    'pattern' => '/[0-9+]',
],
```

But after typing this pattern, my `dropdownlist` is gone. Other patterns working properly, but this, somehow - not. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Try `'/[0-9+]/'` or even `'/^[0-9+]+$/'`

Comment: Eh, first one works. But is it possible for regex to allow just one + sign? F.e only numbers plus just one + sign. I need this, because in the activeform it could happen like: +++++++++1111111

Comment: You mean `'/^[+]?[0-9]+$/'` worked?

Comment: Yep, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii2 requires PHP-like regexps, so, there should be *both* regex delimiters, and since you defined `/` at the start, the same one must be at the end.

If you need to match a string that may start with an optional `+`, and then have 1+ digits, you need to use

```
'/^[+]?[0-9]+$/'
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of the string
- `[+]?` - 1 or 0 plus symbols (as `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences, placing a `+` inside `[...]` lets keep it unescaped)
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits (since `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences)
- `$` - end of string